# React app not working after uploading to Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku

The app i am building works fine in development but when i upload it to heroku it does not work.
Application : https://react-expense-manager-sujan.herokuapp.com/

I am getting followin error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

I think my bundle.js is not working.

Heroku Build LOG:

```
    -----> Node.js app detected
-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       engines.yarn (package.json):  unspecified (use default)

       Resolving node version 8.x...
       Downloading and installing node 8.11.1...
       Using default npm version: 5.6.0
       Resolving yarn version 1.x...
       Downloading and installing yarn (1.6.0)...
       Installed yarn 1.6.0
-----> Restoring cache
       Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules
       - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
-----> Building dependencies
       Installing node modules (yarn.lock)
       yarn install v1.6.0
       [1/4] Resolving packages...
       [2/4] Fetching packages...
       warning Pattern ["object-assign@latest"] is trying to unpack in the same destination "/tmp/yarncache.yn2Gs/v1/npm-object-assign-4.1.1-2109adc7965887cfc05cbbd442cac8bfbb360863" as pattern ["object-assign@^4.1.0","object-assign@^4.1.0","object-assign@^4.1.1","object-assign@^4.0.1","object-assign@^4.0.1","object-assign@^4.0.1","object-assign@^4.1.0","object-assign@^4.1.0","object-assign@^4","object-assign@^4.0.1","object-assign@^4.1.1","object-assign@^4.1.0","object-assign@^4.1.1","object-assign@^4.1.1","object-assign@^4.0.1"]. This could result in non-deterministic behavior, skipping.
       warning Pattern ["send@latest"] is trying to unpack in the same destination "/tmp/yarncache.yn2Gs/v1/npm-send-0.16.2-6ecca1e0f8c156d141597559848df64730a6bbc1" as pattern ["send@0.16.2","send@0.16.2"]. This could result in non-deterministic behavior, skipping.
       info fsevents@1.1.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
       info "fsevents@1.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
       [3/4] Linking dependencies...
       warning " > react-datepicker@1.4.1" has incorrect peer dependency "moment@^2.20.0".
       [4/4] Building fresh packages...
       Done in 21.32s.
       Running heroku-postbuild (yarn)
       yarn run v1.6.0
       $ yarn run build:prod
       $ webpack -p --env production
The CLI moved into a separate package: webpack-cli
       Would you like to install webpack-cli? (That will run yarn add -D webpack-cli) (yes/NO)Done in 0.66s.
-----> Caching build
       Clearing previous node cache
       Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules
       - bower_components (nothing to cache)
-----> Pruning devDependencies
       yarn install v1.6.0
       [1/4] Resolving packages...
       [2/4] Fetching packages...
       warning Pattern ["object-assign@latest"] is trying to unpack in the same destination "/tmp/yarncache.yn2Gs/v1/npm-object-assign-4.1.1-2109adc7965887cfc05cbbd442cac8bfbb360863" as pattern ["object-assign@^4.1.0","object-assign@^4.1.0","object-assign@^4.1.1","object-assign@^4.0.1","object-assign@^4.0.1","object-assign@^4.0.1","object-assign@^4.1.0","object-assign@^4.1.0","object-assign@^4","object-assign@^4.0.1","object-assign@^4.1.1","object-assign@^4.1.0","object-assign@^4.1.1","object-assign@^4.1.1","object-assign@^4.0.1"]. This could result in non-deterministic behavior, skipping.
       warning Pattern ["send@latest"] is trying to unpack in the same destination "/tmp/yarncache.yn2Gs/v1/npm-send-0.16.2-6ecca1e0f8c156d141597559848df64730a6bbc1" as pattern ["send@0.16.2","send@0.16.2"]. This could result in non-deterministic behavior, skipping.
       info fsevents@1.1.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
       info "fsevents@1.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
       [3/4] Linking dependencies...
       warning " > react-datepicker@1.4.1" has incorrect peer dependency "moment@^2.20.0".
       [4/4] Building fresh packages...
       warning Ignored scripts due to flag.
       Done in 5.62s.
-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 41.2M
-----> Launching...
       Released v6
       https://react-expense-manager-sujan.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

My Package.JSON

```
{
  "name": "BoilerPlate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "Sujan",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "live-server public/",
    "build:dev": "webpack",
    "build:prod": "webpack -p --env production",
    "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
    "test": "jest",
    "start" : "node server/server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild" : "yarn run build:prod"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "jest": "^22.4.3",
    "live-server": "^1.2.0",
    "moment": "2.18.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.8.3",
    "react": "^16.3.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^1.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
    "uuid": "^3.2.1",
    "validator": "^9.4.1",
    "webpack": "^4.4.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.1"
  }
}
```

Any Help will be highly appreciated.

NEW ERROR:

```
 ERROR in ./src/routers/AppRouter.js
       Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../components/HelpPage' in '/tmp/build_44d57a1b64b926d484f0d216b8ec1537/src/routers'
       @ ./src/routers/AppRouter.js 29:16-49
       @ ./src/app.js
       Child extract-text-webpack-plugin node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist node_modules/css-loader/index.js??ref--5-1!node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--5-2!src/styles/style.scss:
       Entrypoint undefined = extract-text-webpack-plugin-output-filename
       [1] ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-1!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--5-2!./src/styles/style.scss 1.01 KiB {0} [built]
       + 1 hidden module
       Child extract-text-webpack-plugin node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist node_modules/css-loader/index.js??ref--5-1!node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--5-2!node_modules/react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css:
       Entrypoint undefined = extract-text-webpack-plugin-output-filename
       2 modules
error Command failed with exit code 2.
       info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
       info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
-----> Build failed

       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

       Some possible problems:

       - Node version not specified in package.json
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version

       Love,
       Heroku

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily see the response in chrome for `bundle.js`

[image]

which means you have failed to create bundle on this step

```
  $ webpack -p --env production
The CLI moved into a separate package: webpack-cli
       Would you like to install webpack-cli? (That will run yarn add -D webpack-cli) (yes/NO)Done in 0.66s.
-----> Caching build
```

so probably just run `yarn add webpack-cli` and re-deploy again

Comment: I am getting another error. Please look at the updated question.

Comment: @SujanShrestha please show contents of `AppRouter.js` looks like you have messed up the webpack config, the error is showing that it cand find `Can't resolve '../components/HelpPage' in '/tmp/build_44d57a1b64b926d484f0d216b8ec1537/src/routers'` do you have `src/components/HelpPage.js` in your directory?

Comment: @SujanShrestha also please add engines sections as referred here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version you can add `"node" : "8.9.x"`

Comment: thank you so much. I did a typo there. I created a file helpPage.js. Such a silly mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You have imported a file in AppRouter.js called ../component/HelpPage that does not exist check inside your component folder if there is HelpPage or your path is incorrect in AppRouter.js to import HelpPage.

Comment: thank you so much. I did a typo there. I created a file helpPage.js. Such a silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I was having almost the same error but mine was little different, the error I was facing had to do with the only 1 file named "smartbagContext" so whereever I had imported that file was causing the error though path and filename and everything was correct but when I changed filename to "appContext" it was working correctly.